# Recover PART of a file from DATA portion of drive

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I made the mistake of opening a file up *twice* and updating both versions with different though both important information. I've done file recovery before and have even recovered entire lost partitions (I'm very advanced) though I'd like to recover the text at the beginning of the file that was overwritten if possible (knowing that it *might* or *might not* be overwritten). I know the exact path and file name if that helps. I've tried Recuva but it won't allow me to see raw disk data before or after the file data itself. Suggestions please?

Comment: You cannot recover overwritten data but you can recover the previous version if the new one was allocated to different sectors. How big was the file? What file format? Please provide some relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you probably won't be able to recover that file yourself.  Assuming it's a small text file that fits in a single block on the hard drive, then the most recent save overwrote the whole block.  If it's a larger file it gets much more complicated, but a pro data recovery shop might be able to get it.  If you had Previous Versions turned on, you may be able to get one of the intermediate saves.